# Laptop went blank

Tags: lenovo-laptop

I have connected my laptop charger port to HDMI by mistake. The screen went blank from then. Even the LED lights such as Power are not blinking. Laptop went completely dead. I use a Lenovo L440 model. What should I do. Please help

Answer (score 1):

If it's still under warranty, send it in for a replacement. If it's not, it's time for a new laptop. If you were able to get the power connection into the hdmi port, you were able to provide 20 volts to circuitry designed for 5, and you fried the system board.

Comment: Are you sure? because that laptop is given by my company. If it gets damaged I need to pay them heavily

Comment: @sumanth.ch I don't think he would post this if he wasn't sure.